# Lacie Big 5 10tb to be used as external hard drive but want security so: ZFS Raidz?

Tags: external-disk, raid, zfs

I've just bought the Lacie Big 5 10th and I want to use it as an external hard drive for my files. I was thinking of making it raid1 but then I heard about ZFS and Raidz. so that I can easily change/upgrade individual drives as time goes on

What matters to me is at least 5tb but a real safety for my files. Anybody can help me figure out what I need and how to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do RAID 0 or RAID 6 and just user HFS+ if you're on a Mac.

I think it's best. Although I don't think RAID 6 is an native option in Disk Utility.